# App got crash sometimes when opening my app

Tags: android, android-logcat, android-log

suddenly when opening my app i got one crash and i uploaded the crash log below.But it happens sometime only not every time and every device.

Can anyone help me to understand the crash log and why its happening for sometimes and some devices. what is main reason for the below crash?

```
            Revision: '14'
            ABI: 'arm'
            pid: 1834, tid: 8022, name: pool-3-thread-1 >>> com.example <<<
            signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
            Abort message: 'art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: java_array == null'
            r0 00000000 r1 00001f56 r2 00000006 r3 00000000
            r4 942bfdb8 r5 00000006 r6 00000002 r7 0000010c
            r8 00000000 r9 b4e4f520 sl af17a800 fp 00000965
            ip 00001f56 sp 942bf498 lr b6f26fd5 pc b6f4aeb4 cpsr 60070010


    backtrace:
    #00 pc 00037eb4 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00013fd1 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 00014bef /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00011531 /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0000fcbc /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 0021d161 /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+160)
    #06 pc 000a831b /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
    #07 pc 000b1a49 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1060)
    #08 pc 000b1fa5 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+60)
    #09 pc 001be127 /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetArrayLength(_JNIEnv*, _jarray*)+570)
    #10 pc 00001171 /data/app/com.example-1/lib/arm/library.so (Java_com_example_value_encypt+48)
    #11 pc 004986f9 /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example-1@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Comment: Do you have some NDK code in your app? (Native C++ code)

Comment: You should look your NDK code, this is from there. One of java_array seems to be not initialized.

Comment: Alright, then checl the ndk code, find the 'java_array' variable and add a missing null check. The error is that this variable is null at some point.

Comment: @Kelevandos there is no variable 'java_array". the NDK calls only the GetArrayLength method.

Comment: Alright, then make a nullcheck on this method and return 0 if the reference is null

Comment: even though i did null check same error came @Kelevandos

Comment: Are you sure it is accessed only in this one place?

Comment: yes, this is the only call to that method... @Kelevandos

Answer (score 0):

This kind of crash was happening to my app too. I could not figure it out through the logs. Once, I got hold of a device on which it crashed and found that it was crashing at a place where I was clearing the `WebView` cache. The problem was that the function to do that was deprecated, so in most of the phones it worked while in few others, it crashed. Since this was occurring probably even before `Crashlytics` got initialised, I was not getting any actual crash reports except from these kind of logs from `Play Store`.

What I would suggest is, check the device models from `Play Store`, and try to get a hold of one of these devices and try to see `logcat` crash report as it would point you to the actual problem.